# How to edit contents in Angular js Smart Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, contenteditable, smart-table

I am quite new to java script, so I must apologise if this seems basic.

How can I edit rows tables in Smart-Table with Angularjs? There doesn't seem to be a tutorial with the new Smart-Table. I would like to create a simple form for users to enter the hours open for a particular place.

I have created buttons which can add and remove rows on the table, but when I add in contenteditable="true" none of the changes are persisted when I update the object. I understand that the contenteditable is a specific html5 parameters independent of smart-table, but I don't understand how else I can update the data or how I could retrieve the updated data.

The data is retrieved from the angularjs controller via the mean.js routes.

```
<div class="controls">
    <table st-table="place.openHours" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Opening Time</th>
            <th>Closing Time</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in place.openHours" contenteditable="true" >
            <td>{{row.day}}</td>
            <td>{{row.open}}</td>
            <td>{{row.close}}</td>
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeOpenHour(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                </i>
            </button>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="button" ng-click="addOpenHour(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        </i> Add new Row
    </button>
</div>
```

Inside the javascript:

```
    $scope.removeOpenHour = function removeOpenHour(row) {
        var index = $scope.place.openHours.indexOf(row);
        if (index !== -1) {
            $scope.rowCollection.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    $scope.addOpenHour = function addOpenHour() {
        $scope.place.openHours.push(
        {
            day: 'Monday',
            open: 540,
            close: 1080
        });
    };
```

Comment: I think you need to do a little more work to use contenteditable in Angular. It change the dom directly and you need to catch those changes so Angular will be aware of them. 
https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable/blob/master/angular-contenteditable.js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks I had a look around and used the code from here http://jsfiddle.net/bonamico/cAHz7/ and merged it with my code.

HTML file:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in place.openHours">
   <td><div contentEditable="true" ng-model="row.day">{{row.day}}</div></td>
   <td><div contentEditable="true" ng-model="row.open">{{row.open}}</div></td>
   <td><div contentEditable="true" ng-model="row.close">{{row.close}}</div></td>
   <td>
   <button type="button" ng-click="removeOpenHour(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
      </i>
   </button>
</td>
```

JS file:

```
myApp.directive('contenteditable', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        // view -> model
        elm.bind('blur', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
            });
        });

        // model -> view
        ctrl.render = function(value) {
            elm.html(value);
        };

        elm.bind('keydown', function(event) {
            console.log("keydown " + event.which);
            var esc = event.which == 27,
                el = event.target;

            if (esc) {
                console.log("esc");
                ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());
                el.blur();
                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });

    }
};
});
```

Comment: Contenteditable is not supported on any version of IE. So useless.

Comment: @DotNetGeek: Not sure how that makes it useless. Maybe IE ought not to be behind so much.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is it:

Angular directive :

```
app.directive("markdown", function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {

        value: '='},
    template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value"></span><input ng-blur="blur()" ng-model="value"></input>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        // Let's get a reference to the input element, as we'll want to reference it.
        var inputElement = angular.element(element.children()[1]);

        // This directive should have a set class so we can style it.
        element.addClass('edit-in-place');

        // Initially, we're not editing.
        $scope.editing = false;

        // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
        $scope.edit = function() {
            $scope.editing = true;

            // We control display through a class on the directive itself. See the CSS.
            element.addClass('active');

            // And we must focus the element. 
            // `angular.element()` provides a chainable array, like jQuery so to access a native DOM function, 
            // we have to reference the first element in the array.
            inputElement[0].focus();
        };

        // When we leave the input, we're done editing.

        $scope.blur = function() {
            $scope.editing = false;
            element.removeClass('active');
        }
    }
  };

});
```

HTML:

```
 <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th st-sort="sku">SKU</th>
          <th st-sort="skuSupplier">SKU proveedor</th>
          <th st-sort="name">Descripción</th>
          <th st-sort="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
          <th st-sort="precio">Precio unitario</th>
          <th st-sort="total">Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th colspan="5"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar producto ..." type="text"/></th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
          <td><markdown value="row.sku"></markdown></td>
          <td><markdown value="row.skuSupplier"></markdown></td>
          <td><markdown value="row.name"></markdown></td>
          <td><markdown value="row.cantidad"></markdown></td>
          <td><markdown value="row.precio"></markdown></td>
          <td><markdown value="row.total"></markdown></td>
          <td>
              <button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i>
              </button>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Whenever I type something into the textbox it shows twice, one inside the textBox & other outside the textbox, can you please have a look? @user3809100