# How to handle dates from database with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting data from SQLite and assign it to my $scope.loans:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "book_id": 2,
    "patron_id": 3,
    "loaned_on": "2016-12-28",
    "return_by": "2017-01-25",
    "returned_on": "2017-01-17",
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "book_id": 3,
    "patron_id": 4,
    "loaned_on": "2016-12-28",
    "return_by": "2017-01-25",
    "returned_on": null,
}
```

In my view I'm trying to bind the data into inputs tags so the user can edit and submit the changes (I'm using pug template engine)

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th Loaned On
      th Return By
      th Returned On
  tbody
    tr(ng-repeat='loan in loans')
      td(type='date' ng-model='loan.loaned_on' value='{{loan.loaned_on}}')
      td(type='date' ng-model='loan.loaned_on' value='{{loan.return_by}}')
      td(type='date' ng-model='loan.loaned_on' value='{{loan.returned_on}}')
```

Now I'm getting an AngularJS error says that the ngModel is not a date object.
I understand that I should use the date constructor to convert the date string to a date object, But my question is what is the best way to do such a thing?

## solution

I thought that maybe I'll find a better way, but I didn't.
So I loop through the loans array and assign a date object for each date string.

Comment: youloking for a smart table and have solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28502150/6617798)

Comment: you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28502150/6617798) has a solution for your table

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating a date

You can simply use the default constructor of `Date`, if your date is in this ISO 8601 form.

```
new Date("2017-01-25")
```

If you want to do some calculations with the date or if you want to pass the date in another format, I would recommend using [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/):

```
var myDate = moment("2017-01-25", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var newDate = myDate.add(7, "days");
```

---

#### Passing it to the scope

The simplest way to pass the `Date` to the HTML is to pass it in a scope function. In this way, you can simply call it in the HTML.

**Controller (with Date Constructor):**

```
$scope.createDate = function(dateString) {
    return new Date(dateString);
};
```

**Controller (with `moment.js`):**

```
$scope.createDate = function(dateString) {
    return moment("2017-01-25", "YYYY-MM-DD");
};
```

**HTML (pug template)**:

```
td(type='date' ng-model='createDate(loan.loaned_on)' value='{{loan.loaned_on}}')
```

Comment: The value of the input is not the problem, the `ng-model` requires the modal to be a date object. and you can't pass a function inside it..

Comment: You do not pass a function but rather the return value of this function - which is a `Date` object. You only need the expression to be executed. If `createDate(loan.loaned_on)` is passed as String, try `ng-model='{{createDate(loan.loaned_on)}}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this, which is simple and inline.

```
td(type='date' ng-model='new Date(loan.loaned_on)' value='{{loan.loaned_on}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave the input type as `date` but you assigning date string to the `model` which the `model` is not expecting. Instead, convert the value to a date object and assign it as shown below :

```
tbody
tr(ng-repeat='loan in loans')
  td(type='date' ng-model='loan.loaned_on' value='{{new Date(loan.loaned_on)}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.loans = [{
    "id": 1,
    "book_id": 2,
    "patron_id": 3,
    "loaned_on": "2016-12-28",
    "return_by": "2017-01-25",
    "returned_on": "2017-01-17"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "book_id": 3,
    "patron_id": 4,
    "loaned_on": "2016-12-28",
    "return_by": "2017-01-25",
    "returned_on": null
}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Loaned On</th> 
        <th>Return By</th>
        <th>Returned On</th>   
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='loan in loans'>
        <td><input type='date' ng-model='loan.loaned_on' value='{{loan.loaned_on}}'/></td>
      <td><input type='date' ng-model='loan.return_by' value='{{loan.return_by}}'/></td>
      <td><input type='date' ng-model='loan.returned_on' value='{{loan.returned_on}}'/></td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```